# AndroidX Fragment recyclerview appearing over my toolbar and I need the recyclerview to scroll under the toolbar

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, androidx

I've created a AndroidX app using a main Activity with fragments.  When I go to my fragment with the recyclerview the recycler view appears over the toolbar for the app.  What I need is for the recyclerview to appear below the tool bar...

This is the main view with toolbar

[image: MainView with Toolbar]

This is the fragment with the recyclerview appearing over that toolbar :

[image]

Code for activity_mail.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav_view"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/toolbar"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">




        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_text"
                app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_background"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="#002B49"
                app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*EDIT* Here is the layout for toolbar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/products_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/black"
            local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/rsi_logo"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/menubutton"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

As an added note this occurs on fragment's with scrollviews as well.

Comment: did you figured this out?

Comment: to figure out exact problem, without suggesting a new layout structure. Please share your code in repository where we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I did not figure it out yet.  Unfortunately I can't share the repo.

Comment: and what is `@layout/toolbar`?

Comment: @MartinZeitler just added it.

Comment: @yams please take a look at the answer below and leave a response

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your problem ([created a repo](https://github.com/kaushalyap/toolbar-hidden-issue)), but I did not find the issue you specified.

**Screenshot**: Toolbar is shown

[image]

So I say that most probably the issue is with your `view.RecyclerFragment` code. It seems that you are hiding your the toolbar in your `view.RecyclerFragment`
It's better if you can share your `view.RecyclerFragment` code also.

Comment: this took me some time hope you find it useful

Comment: It's actually not a problem with the recyclerfragment code and your code for the main layout is different which is why you couldn't reproduce the issue. Also your view doesn't contain the scroll view as well!.

Comment: @yams actual yours and mine [main_activity](https://github.com/kaushalyap/toolbar-hidden-issue/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) is almost identical. Anyway upvotes are appreciated if it was helpful.

Comment: one thing I failed to mention is that this behavior happens on fragments with scrollviews as well.

Comment: @yams can you give me a reproducible example.